# SignalR, MEF and Dependency Injection working together

Tags: model-view-controller, dependency-injection, signalr, mef

I'm trying to get SignalR, MEF, and MVC working together.

Here is my resolver class:

```
public class SignalRDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer _container;

    public SignalRDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");
        }

        var name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);
        var export = _container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<object>(name);
        return export;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");
        }

        var exports = _container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        return exports;
    }
}
```

And here is my Owin startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var resolver = new SignalRDependencyResolver(MefConfigWeb.Container);
        var config = new HubConfiguration
        {
            Resolver = resolver,
        };

        app.MapSignalR(config);
    }
}
```

I can break on Startup class and see that the container does include my exports. However, Visual Studio prompts with an exception:

> Unhandled exception at line 244, column 13 in
>   `http://localhost:3928/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.js`
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SignalR: Error loading hubs.
>   Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. .

The app works fine if I don't set my custom dependency resolver and New up my dependency inside the Hub class.

I am following along from this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the base implementation when you don't have the service.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I guess my follow up question would be why do I have to add an export attribute on the hub class for my imports to be hydrated? Isn't the resolver supposed to do this when it looks inside hub class and sees a property that needs to be imported?

Comment: You need to ask the designers of MEF that question.